# Is it possible to send SMS after Maintenance plan succeed in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have created a maintenance plan. I want that When maintenance plan complete it's work a SMS should be send to my mobile.

I found alert feature in Sql Server but it for sending Email.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Does your company have an SMS service set up through email (e.g. PhoneNumber@sms.companyname.com)? That would probably be your best bet. Or google it; https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2922/sql-server-alerts-with-text-messaging-from-sql-server-database-mail/

Comment: Thanks.... Let me check.

Comment: maybe a CLR procedure can be triggered after maintenance is completed